Plotly ScatterGeo Text color
I'm using plotly to make a choropleth map.
I would like to add text labels to the map using fig.add_scattergeo, but it's borrowing the colormapping from the plot and it doesn't look good. The text doesn't contrast with the background color and it is difficult to read.
I would like to know if and how I can modify the text traces produced by fig.add_scattergeo to have better contrast.

Code:
# Create a choropleth map with state names
fig = px.choropleth(
    top_sectors_empl,
    locations="st",  # Column with state names
    locationmode="USA-states",  # Set location mode for U.S. states
    color="ds_state_sector_headcount",  # Column with data to visualize
    scope="usa",  # Restrict to the U.S.
    title="Highest Employing Sector by State",  # Title for the map
    color_continuous_scale="Viridis",  # Color scale
    # labels={"value": "Value"},  # Label for the legend
)
fig.update_coloraxes(
    dict(
        colorbar=dict(
            title="Annual Salary",
        )
    )
)
fig.add_scattergeo(
    locations=top_sectors_empl["st"],
    locationmode="USA-states",
    text=top_sectors_empl["short_sector"],
    mode="text")

# Save the figure as an HTML file
fig.write_html("choropleth_map_empl.html")


os.system("open choropleth_map_empl.html")


maybe make the text white?

I can't figure out how to modify the text.

You can change the color of the scattergeo text using the marker parameter:
fig.add_scattergeo(
    locations=top_sectors_empl["st"],
    locationmode="USA-states",
    text=top_sectors_empl["short_sector"],
    marker=dict(color='white'),
    mode="text")

